# Automatically rebuild cache

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, symfony1, doctrine

I run a Symfony 1.4 project with very large amount of data. The main page and category pages are using pagers which need to know how much rows are available. I'm passing a query which contains joins to the pager which leads to a loading-time of 1 minute on these pages.

I configured cache.yml for the respective actions. But I think the workaround is insufficient and here are my assumptions:

Symfony rebuilds the cache within a single request which is made by a user. Let's call this user "cache-victim" to simplify things.

In our case, the data needs to be up-to-update - a lifetime of 10 minutes would be sufficient. Obviously, the cache won't be rebuilt, if no user is willing to be the "cache-victim" and therefore just cancels the request. Are these assumptions correct?

So, I came up with this idea:
Symfony should fake the http-request after rebuilding the cache. The new cache-entries should be written on a temporary file/directory and should be swapped with the previous cache-entries, as soon as cache rebuilding has finished.

Is this possible?

In my opinion, this is similar to the concept of double buffering.

Wouldn't it be silly, if there was a single "gpu-victim" in a multiplayer game who sees the screen building up line by line? (This is a lop-sided comparison, I know ... ;) )

**Edit**

There is no "cache-victim" - Every 10 minutes page reloading takes 1 minute for every user.

Comment: To be frank, I'd first look into why counting rows for a pager (if I understood correctly?) takes 1 minute to complete. Either way the obvious problem to solve is the loading time with a stale cache. Secondly, a user cancelling a request typically does not prevent the webserver to complete running the request (unless it times out or reached another limit).

Comment: Okay, then "processing the request" would be cancelled. It takes 1 minute due to the large amount of data and joins. The pager-query itself is very simple. The pager needs to know the count of entries, because it calculates how much pages are available.

Comment: I'm suggesting you should work on that first, I don't see a sensible explanation on why populating a pager should take that long. I am sure you can optimize that, but can't comment further without knowing the specifics.

Comment: hmm, 'select * from articles' takes about 45 seconds. The table has 130000 rows. When trying to add a limit, the symfony pager silently removes it :/ When adding a "created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR"-condition the query takes as long as without the condition. I'm trying this locally and on the production server => similar results

Comment: That is not normal behaviour, the standard pager class in symfony would add a limit, depending on the page size you set up, and perform an additional COUNT() query on the whole table. Neither of these two queries should take 45s. You might want to paste your code for the pager.

Comment: The sql-query above takes 45 seconds from mysql-cli - is this abnormal, too? The limit is added for the pager-results itself and removed (of course) for the count() query: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_11/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/pager/sfDoctrinePager.class.php#L106 The idea was to apply two limits, one for the pages and a second one for the entries per page.

Comment: @Gerry let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1213/discussion-between-fishbone-and-gerry)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to some missing or wrong indexes. I've a sf1.4 project for a large soccer site (i.e. 2M pages/day) and pagers aren't going so slow even if our database has more than 1M rows these days. Take a look at your query with EXPLAIN and check where it is going bad...

Comment: I tried that with EXPLAIN and optimized indexes. We upgraded our hardware and that made things better. However, you didn't answer my question. I asked whether the concept of cache swapping is possible. Why must users wait when building the new cache entry? - old cache entries are still available.

Comment: I don't see the point. Yes, cache swapping is possible but this solution is only for some very critical scenarios. And I think you can solve it in another way working on your db stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necromancing (is there a badge for that?).
By configuring cache.yml you are just caching the view layer of your app (that is, css, js and html) for REQUESTS WITHOUT PARAMETERS. Navigating the pager obviously has a ?page=X on the GET request.

Taken from symfony 1.4 config.yml documentation:

> An incoming request with GET parameters in the query string or submitted with the POST, PUT, or DELETE method will never be cached by symfony, regardless of the configuration. http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/09-Cache

What might help you is to cache the database results, but its a painful process on symfony/doctrine. Refer to:
http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_using_doctrine_result_caching

Edit:
This might help you as well:
http://www.zalas.eu/symfony-meets-apc-alternative-php-cache